# Url routing asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I am trying to create url routing like this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx

but I am having few questions , first why he is adding lines to the web.config , I tested it and it didnt appear that they're doing something as I commented them and nothing major appeared

second I am having this line of code that is crashing
 var display = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(_virtualPath,typeof(Page)) as IProfileHandler;

when casted as ihttphandler it's working , but when I am casting it to iprofilehandler(which is implemeting ihttphandler) it's giving null !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article is quite old as it's written before ASP.NET 4.0 was released.

Routing is now a core component of ASP.NET 4.

See this one instead:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: mmmmm...well I liked one thing the guy did , he is making the page strongly typed...It's like I am not members of interface instead of strings to get the values that I want , aint that an advantage ??

Comment: I don't see why you can't do that with the other API, but generally speaking, this is the supported scenario anyway. You may give another question on you'd wish to use it and I may help answering how to tweak it to the code prototype you feel appropriate.

Comment: sure , here is it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640344/url-routing-with-strongly-typed-objects

Answer (score 0):

These are really two questions here:

1. *Why he is adding lines to the web.config* - Web Configuration in .NET 4.0 applications has been greatly streamlined.  A lot of the configuration that was done per-application is now included in the lower level web configuration (machine wide) ([read](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/25/clean-web-config-files-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)).  This means you don't need to add that configuration data in, its already done for you.
2. You're issue with `BuildManager` returning `null`. We'd need to see a little more code than that.

Comment: Mathew , the other code than this is that I am writing an empty interface called IProfileHandler that's implemeting ihttphanlder , anything else you want?