# url routing with strongly typed objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, routes

I am trying to create url routing with strongly typed objects for pages but I keep getting null object on the first line so it's crashing

```
//Getting the suitable executing Page
var display = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(_virtualPath,typeof(Page)) as IProfileHandler;
//Setting Page Parameters
display.MemberId = Convert.ToInt32(requestContext.RouteData.Values["ID"]);
//Return Page
return display;

public interface IProfileHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    int MemberId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which object is null? display or requestContext? If it's display, when you debug is the build manager returning an object, but it's just not of type IProfileHandler?

Comment: display is null , It returns null when I am casting to iprofilehandler , it returns the specified object when i am casting to ihttphandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those who pass by here , here is what I did , i added few properties to my page class and I am casting to that class , which seems good and nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath` isn't returning an object that implements `IProfileHandler`.

*Edit:*

You're trying to cast the return object to an `IProfileHandler`. That means you're saying "Ok Compiler, I know this method returns an `object`, but I promise it's already an instance that implements `IProfileHandler`." Since the `CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath` method was created without the knowledge of your custom class, it has no way to return an object that is guaranteed to follow the contract set by your custom interface (have a property `int MemberId`). Because the object can't be casted properly and you are using the `as` operator, you are getting null. Had you done a normal cast, an `InvalidCastException` would have been thrown.

I'm not sure if I'm the appropriate person to answer how you'd implement it since I've never done any work with HttpHandlers, but according to [this documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) it looks like you'd create a class that implements IHttpHandler, modify your web.config to use the new handler and then cast it to your new class. Maybe something like

```
public class ProfileHttpHandler: IHttpHandler
{
    public int MemberId { get; set; }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            // return value here
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // custom request processing here
    }
}
```

with a web.config entry of

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
         <add verb="*" path="*.yourIntendedExtension" type="FQN, Assembly" />
      </httpHandlers>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It returns an object implementing ihttphandler , and i am creating an interface thats implementing iprofilehandler , why it's not working ?!? and if it doesnt work , what method i shall use?

Comment: @user510336... try reading that sentence again (and again and again)... now, answer me. What is the thing that the two classes have  in common?... now, you're allowed to cast to THAT THEY HAVE IN COMMON, nothing else.